# $(-1)^{0.2}=0.8090 + 0.5878i$ how can this be?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, matlab

I'm working on a numerical analysis project (working with matlab a lot) and I noticed that when I ask for matlab to compute the exponent of a negative number, it gives wrong output when the exponent is not an integer.

For example like the title, when I input $(-1)^{0.2}$ in my calculator, it says $1$, which is the correct answer, if I know anything about how exponents work.

This is because $(-1)^{0.2}=((-1)^2)^{0.1}=1^{0.1}=1$

However, when I put it in matlab, it gives the output $0.8090 + 0.5878i$ how can this be?

On the other hand, $(-1)^{0.2}=((-1)^{0.1})^2$ and $(-1)^{0.1}$ is indeed a complex number. So on the one hand it has an imaginary part, and on the other hand it doesn't...I'm very confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common misconception about powers of negative numbers. The rule $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b$ only works for positive $x$. The reason we restrict to positive $x$ is that powers become a bit mysterious in some sense if $x<0$. Solving $x = (-1)^{.2}$ can be thought of as solving for those $x$ so that $x^5 = -1$ instead. Is $1$ a solution to this equation?

Comment: no, $1$ isn't a solution to this equation. But why is solving $x=(-1)^2$ the same as solving $x^5=-1$?

Comment: Well think about it. What does $x = (-1)^{.2}$ even mean? It means that when you raise $x$ to the power of $5$ you get $-1$. This is how to think of powers. Much the same way as asking what does $x = 8^{.5}$ mean? It means $x$ is a number such that when you square it you get $8$.

Comment: Yes ofcourse...I misread $2$ for $0.2$

Comment: Oh I see. My apologies. Hopefully the further explanation helped though!

Answer (score 1):

Using complex number $(-1)^{0.2} = (-1)^{\frac{1}{5}}$, and view it as taking the $5th $ root of $-1$. DeMoivre's theorem?

Comment: In particular, matlab is only giving one of 5 possible solutions.

Comment: So there is no fallacy in $(-1)^{0.2}=((-1)^2)^{0.1}=1^{0.1}=1$, it's just one of many possible solutions that matlab chose to omit?

Comment: One fallacy there is that you add solutions by squaring -1, in exactly the same way that $x=-\sqrt 2 \implies x^2 = 2 \not \implies x = 2$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Large\sqrt[n]x\quad\it\text{ is a SET of n numbers, and NOT a single solution !!!}$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\big($ *Just sayin'* $\ldots\big)$

The reason mathematical software systems return complex valued quantities for odd-order radicals of negative numbers is because they always seek out the one with the smallest argument $($i.e., the one which creates the smallest angle with the real positive semiaxis$)$. Obviously, the angle made by the negative and positive semiaxes is $180^\circ$, which is greater, in this case, than $\dfrac{360^\circ}5=72^\circ$, and the same goes for all $n>2$.

Comment: I think you mean $x^{1/n}$, not $\sqrt[n]{x}$.

Comment: Those are the same thing unless we want to be strict that latter carries with it's specific unit while the former refers to all possible units

Comment: @CameronWilliams: There's absolutely no difference between the two. The only reason people might think that there is one is because the former notation is more popular, being used even by people unfamiliar with higher mathematical concepts, hence creating the illusion that the latter alone is to be used in such cases, when -in fact- they're exactly the same.

Comment: I've always understood the expression with the root sign to mean principal $n$th root. That was my point.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Every radical implies a choice, and that is indeed the one that we usually, though not always, select. But choice presupposes a plurality of possible options.

Comment: Hmm very good point. I see where you're coming from now. Thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration of the problem with this convention for roots of negative numbers:

$$ (-1)^{2/5} = 1 $$
$$ (-1)^{19/47} = -1 $$
$$ (-1)^{2 \sqrt{2} / 7} = \text{undefined} $$

which would mean

$$ (-1)^{0.4} = 1 $$
$$ (-1)^{0.404\ldots} = -1 $$
$$ (-1)^{0.404\ldots} = \text{undefined} $$

That's a pretty drastic difference for numbers that are so close together, isn't it?

Really, if you want to stick to floating point real numbers, then negative numbers raised to floating point numbers is nonsense, since negligible errors in the exponent make a dramatic difference in the actual value... or if the value is even defined at all!